# How to excute a function only once for same argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

My function call is given below:

```
await insertingMatchIdsInAllTeamPlayers(fieldersA, matchID)
```

Suppose the function is called with matchID '1', it should get executed, but if the function is called again with matchId '1'(It will in my case), it should not be executed. However, if it is called with id '2' (basically id !== '1'), it should be executed. I don't care for fieldersA argument.

Comment: What you are looking for is called *memoisation*. You'll find lots of solutions with that search term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could track all passed arguments in array outside of the function. When you call the function, it will check, if the supplied argument is in the array. If it's not, call the function and insert the argument into the array. If the argument is already in the array, don't call the function.

```js
const suppliedMatchIDs = [];

function insertingMatchIdsInAllTeamPlayers(fieldersA, matchID) {
    if (suppliedMatchIDs.includes(matchID)) {
      return;
    } else {
      suppliedMatchIDs.push(matchID);
    }

    // Your function here
}
```

The general concept of [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) arguments to speed up function calls is called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: The similar approach work for me.  Inside the function, at the bottom, I save the matchId argument in database.

Answer (score 0):

```
const matchIdFirstTimeOne = true
if(matchId === 1 && matchIdFirstTimeOne) {
  await insertingMatchIdsInAllTeamPlayers(fieldersA, matchID);
  matchIFirstTimeOne = false
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Using [closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) could solve it.

```
var insertingMatchIdsInAllTeamPlayers = (function() {
    var executed = [];
    return function(fieldersA,val) {
        if (executed.indexOf(val) == -1) {
            executed.push(val);
            console.log(val);
        }
    };
})();

insertingMatchIdsInAllTeamPlayers('',1); // console.log(1)
insertingMatchIdsInAllTeamPlayers('',1); // 
insertingMatchIdsInAllTeamPlayers('',2); // console.log(2)
insertingMatchIdsInAllTeamPlayers('',2); // 
insertingMatchIdsInAllTeamPlayers('',3); // console.log(3)
```